# Passay password without repeating char sequence

Tags: java, security, passwords

I'm using the passay library for validating password against a list of requirements:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.passay</groupId>
    <artifactId>passay</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

One of my requirements is that a password must not have any sequence of characters immediately followed by the same sequence. For instance:

- **apple**: should be rejected because 'p' is followed by another 'p'.
- **banana**: should be rejected because 'an' is followed by 'an'.
- **123xy123**: is ok because '123' is not immediately followed by '123'.

I tried using `RepeatCharactersRule` ([javadocs](http://www.passay.org/javadocs/org/passay/RepeatCharactersRule.html)), but that Rule is only for sequence of the same characters (it will find 'aaa', but not 'abab').

Does passay have any rule for doing this or will I have to write a custom rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't think it does, but you don't have to write your own rule, try this if you want:

```java
public class RepeatingSequenceRegexTest {
    final PasswordValidator validator = new PasswordValidator(
            new IllegalRegexRule("(.{1,})\\1")
    );

    @Test
    public void checks() {
        assertTrue(validator.validate(new PasswordData("normal")).isValid());
        assertTrue(validator.validate(new PasswordData("abcdef")).isValid());
        assertTrue(validator.validate(new PasswordData("abacadaeaf")).isValid());
        assertTrue(validator.validate(new PasswordData("xyzxy")).isValid());
        assertTrue(validator.validate(new PasswordData("12345")).isValid());
        assertTrue(validator.validate(new PasswordData("121314")).isValid());
        assertTrue(validator.validate(new PasswordData("1234123121")).isValid());
        assertTrue(validator.validate(new PasswordData("123xy123")).isValid());
        assertTrue(validator.validate(new PasswordData("1")).isValid());
        assertTrue(validator.validate(new PasswordData("")).isValid());

        assertFalse(validator.validate(new PasswordData("apple")).isValid());
        assertFalse(validator.validate(new PasswordData("banana")).isValid());
        assertFalse(validator.validate(new PasswordData("112233")).isValid());
        assertFalse(validator.validate(new PasswordData("123123")).isValid());
        assertFalse(validator.validate(new PasswordData("1212")).isValid());
        assertFalse(validator.validate(new PasswordData("11")).isValid());
        assertFalse(validator.validate(new PasswordData("123xy123xy")).isValid());
    }
}
```

Comment: This regex worked perfectly. I was not familiar with '\1' (back references).